# Google-Maps JSF support and other support

Tags: google-maps

We have been using GMaps4JSF 1.1.4 in our application using JSF on JBOSS EPP 5.1. It seems to be working fine but during some testing we found that:

1. If we search for 'al raha beach' in google maps, it returns correct address.
2. But if we search same thing in our application (using gmaps4jsf), nothing is coming; blank map is shown.
3. Same behavior is seen when we search 'al raha beach' on gmaps4jsf demo i.e. on http://www.mashups4jsf.com/gmaps4jsf-examples/pages/getMyLocation.jsf.

We found some other issues also similar to above problem.

I posted question on gmaps4jsf issues list but nobody is responding there. We are looking for answers of following question:

1. Is gmaps4jsf is officially supported by Google for using maps with JSF or it is a kind of community version??
2. Is some team actively supporting the issues found in gmaps4jsf??
3. We want to upgrade to Google Maps version 3.0 - i.e. GMaps4JSF 3.0.0; When can we get this upgraded gmaps4jsf??
4. What is Google Maps (maps.google.com) using internally?? Is there an option to provide users the same user experience which they get on maps.google.com - if yes then using which APIs??

If you can answer any of above problems, then please. Many thanks for responding.

Comment: I don't think that google makes any support for gmaps4jsf. you can  try primefaces for gmaps within jsf. here is demo: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/gmapHome.jsf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GMaps4JSF](http://www.mashups4jsf.com/gmaps4jsf-examples/home.jsf) is not a Google library. It is an open source project powered by community members. In order to make sure that your question will be answered, you need to post your questions to the mailing list: 
gmaps4jsf-dev@googlegroups.com.

About GMaps4JSF 3.0.0, we are expected to release it by the end of this year hopefully.

Hazem Saleh
GMaps4JSF Founder

Comment: Hi, consider registering your account, you've now at least a duplicate unregistered account: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1366224/hazem-saleh

Comment: @Hazem Saleh: We may not have permission to post messages to the group.